# Customize section numbering from Springer templates

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I really like the style of Springer book (which is available [here](http://www.springer.com/authors/book+authors?SGWID=0-154102-12-970131-0)), so I decided to customize it for my own book.

In that template, the section in chapter is labelled as : 1.1 (1st section in chapter 1), x.y(xth section in chapter y).

I want to change numbering the section in each chapter by `arabic`, start with `1,...`.

So, how can I do it ?

Comment: It seems like `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` should do that. I'm not entirely clear on the current numbering scheme. Perhaps you could provide a visual in the form of some ASCII art?

Comment: @Werner : It solved. Thank you so much.To mod : this question is quite local, so please help me to delete it. Thanks

Comment: @NguyễnDuyKhánh: There is, I think, no need to delete this question, unless we find out it is a duplicate of another question.  It is quite likely that other Latex users might want to know how to change the numbering on Springer styles, so I think this question is certainly not too localized.